# Can a list of all member-dict keys be created from a dict of dicts using a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-3.5

Say I have a dict of dicts:

```
foo = {
    'category': {
        'key1': 'bar',
        'key2': 'bar',
        'key3': 'bar',
    },
    'category2': {
        'key4': 'bar',
        'key5': 'bar',
    },
}
```

To get a single list of all keys in the member-dicts, I have a function as follows:

```
def _make_list():
    baz = list()
    for key,val in foo.items():
        baz += list(val.keys())
    return baz
```

The generated list looks like: `['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', ]`.

This is simple enough, and it works, but I wonder: **is there a way to accomplish this with a one-liner list comprehension**? The keys of the member dicts will always be unique.

Comment: Btw your `+= list(..)` should really be `.extend(...)`

Comment: And `.items()` is not really necessary if you are only using the values; `.values()` is enough.

Comment: Do you really want a list of all the keys including duplicates? If not a set might be more appropriate: `set(itertools.chain(*foo.values()))` based on ettanany's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
>>> [k for d in foo.values() for k in d]
['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I've marked it as accepted, as this is exactly what I was looking for. Would you consider explaining how it works?

Answer (score 3):

An approach would be using [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

[k for k in itertools.chain(*(d.keys() for d in foo.values()))]
```

If what you want is just a one line of code, and not necessarily a list comprehension, you can also try (mentioned by @Duncan):

```
list(itertools.chain(*foo.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [k for k in itertools.chain(*(d.keys() for d in foo.values()))]
['key3', 'key2', 'key1', 'key5', 'key4']
>>>
>>> list(itertools.chain(*foo.values()))
['key3', 'key2', 'key1', 'key5', 'key4']
```

Comment: `[k for k in ...]` is generally better written as just `list(...)`, also `d.keys()` could just be `d` here and `(d for d in ...)` can also be collapsed giving `list(itertools.chain(*foo.values()))`

Comment: @Duncan I agree with you, just want to use list comprehension because the OP asked for that. I edited this answer to add your remark!

Comment: Today I learned how to use itertools chain. I had a method for this as well but its not nearly as clean. I also used chain.fromiterable() in mine.